# Fitbit Authorization page - How to disabled checkboxes?

Tags: java, authorization, apiclient

I am working on a web application that integrates with Fitbit. I have a question on the Authoriztion page in Authorization Code Grant Flow: Is it possible to prevent the user from unchecking the checkboxes, e.g.: disable the checkboxes? Please see the attached screenshot below.

Any help would be appreciated!

[image]